# How to check if text box value is within particular range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i wan to validate the entered input in text-box is within range or not.

I have two text-box in react

```
<InputGroup size="sm">
    <Input name="input1" type="number" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress.bind(this)}  value={this.state.point1}
    onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'point1')}
    onBlur={() => this.setSliderValueFromInput('point1')} />
</InputGroup>
<InputGroup size="sm" >
    <Input name="input2" type="number" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress.bind(this)} value={this.state.point2}
    onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'point2')}
    onBlur={() => this.setSliderValueFromInput('point2')} />
</InputGroup>
```

and this function to insure that entered number should be numeric only

```
onKeyPress(event) {
    const keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    const keyValue = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
     if (/\+|-/.test(keyValue))
       event.preventDefault();
   }
```

now i want that for input1 text-box if entered input is outside the particular range (1.2 to 3.2) then turn textbox border color red( to show error).

This is very simple problem but i am very new in react an d JavaScript to could not solve it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with inline styles:

```
<InputGroup size="sm" >
    <Input 
    name="input2" 
    type="number" 
    value={this.state.point2}
    style={
        this.state.point2 < 1.2 || this.state.point2 > 3.2 ? 
        {border: '1px solid red'} :
        {}
    }
    onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress.bind(this)} 
    onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'point2')}
    onBlur={() => this.setSliderValueFromInput('point2')} />
</InputGroup>
```